# What is the RESTFul way of representing URLs when creating the same object using a single URL structure but can call different server methods?

Tags: rest, http, api-design

Say I have an endpoint for creating an object that takes time to complete which has the following URL structure: `/api/v1/objects`.

Business rules dictate that API consumers can either call this endpoint synchronously or asynchronously in the server. The result of this call in the end is the creation of the same object, but response upon submission of the endpoint is different between the two depending on whether it is called synchronously or asynchronously (i.e. if the call is made asynchronously, a consumer may get an identifier with no guarantee if the object will be created or not, while calling the endpoint synchronously will always create the object and return it in the response.)

Right now I have this structure for distinguishing between the synchronous and asynchronous API calls:

- `POST /api/v1/objects` - for creating the object synchronously.
- `POST /api/v1/objects?async=true` - for creating the object
  asynchronously.

Is this approach correct and conforms to RESTFul principles?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the RFC for HTTP (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.1.1 ) you can see the `Expect` header, which basically defines what behaviour the client is expecting from the server.

Considering you can have different `20*` responses (`200`, `201`, `202`, `204`), you can use this to determine whether it should be async or not.

A quick Google search comes up with [this example](https://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html) (which I copy and paste here for future reference):

> A client may request the server to modify its asynchronous behavior
> with the following “Expect” headers:
>
> - **“Expect: 200-ok/201-created/204-no-content”** disables all asynchronous
>   functionality. The server may return a “417 Expectation Failed” if it
>   is not willing to wait for an operation to complete.
> - **“Expect: 202-accepted”** explicitly request an asynchronous response. The server
>   may return a “417 Expectation Failed” if it is not willing to perform
>   the request asynchronously. If no expectation is provided, client must
>   be prepared to accept a 202 Accepted status for any request other than
>   GET.